# code works fine on pc but not on foobar interpreter

Tags: python

I'm working on a coding problem on level 3 in foobar challenge(prepare the bunnies escape). Code works fine on PC but doesn't verify tests on foobar interpreter.

This is the problem:

You have maps of parts of the space station, each starting at a work area exit and ending at the door to an escape pod. The map is represented as a matrix of 0s and 1s, where 0s are passable space and 1s are impassable walls. The door out of the station is at the top left (0,0) and the door into an escape pod is at the bottom right (w-1,h-1).

Write a function solution(map) that generates the length of the shortest path from the station door to the escape pod, where you are allowed to remove one wall as part of your remodeling plans. The path length is the total number of nodes you pass through, counting both the entrance and exit nodes. The starting and ending positions are always passable (0). The map will always be solvable, though you may or may not need to remove a wall. The height and width of the map can be from 2 to 20. Moves can only be made in cardinal directions; no diagonal moves are allowed.

and this is my code:

```
class state:   
    
    def __init__(self,x,y,last_move,wall,path,map) -> None:
        self.x = x 
        self.y = y

        self.last_move = last_move   # Prevent Backtracking
        self.wall = wall
        self.path = path


    # MAP[x][y] = 1 => WALL
    # WALL = TRUE IF ALREADY ENCOUNTERED WALL
    def can_pass(self,map):
        global wall
        result = not(self.wall and map[self.x][self.y]) # NAND Function
        return result
    
    def new_wall(self,map):
        return self.wall or map[self.x][self.y]


    def create_children_states(self,map):
        moves = ["RIGHT","UP","DOWN","LEFT"] 
#Avoid backtracking
        if self.last_move == "RIGHT":
            moves.remove("LEFT")
        elif self.last_move == "LEFT":
            moves.remove("RIGHT")
        elif self.last_move == "UP":
            moves.remove("DOWN")
        elif self.last_move == "DOWN":
            moves.remove("UP")
        
        self.children_states=[]
        for move in moves:
            if self.can_pass(map):
                if move == "RIGHT" and stays_inbounds(self.y+1,targetY):
                    self.children_states.append(state(self.x,self.y + 1,move,self.new_wall(map),self.path+1,map))   # X, Y+1
                elif move == "UP" and stays_inbounds(self.x-1,targetX):
                    self.children_states.append(state(self.x - 1,self.y,move,self.new_wall(map),self.path+1,map))   # X-1, Y
                elif move == "DOWN" and stays_inbounds(self.x+1,targetX):
                    self.children_states.append(state(self.x + 1,self.y,move,self.new_wall(map),self.path+1,map))   # X+1 , Y 

                elif move == "LEFT" and stays_inbounds(self.y-1,targetY):
                    self.children_states.append(state(self.x,self.y - 1,move,self.new_wall(map),self.path+1,map))  # X , Y-1

    
def stays_inbounds(x,target): # Doesn't leave map
    return x <= target and x >= 0


def solution(map):
    global targetX
    global targetY
    targetX = len(map) - 1
    targetY = len(map[0]) - 1

    queue = [state(0,0,'',False,1,map)]

    while len(queue) > 0: 
        curr_state = queue.pop(0)
        if curr_state.x == targetX and curr_state.y == targetY: # Solution Found
            return curr_state.path
        else:
            curr_state.create_children_states(map)
            for child in curr_state.children_states:
                queue.append(child)
```

Input:
solution.solution([[0, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 0]])
Output:
7

Input:
solution.solution([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
Output:
11

I get expected outputs on local interpreter but not on foobar interpreter

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem (unfortunately too late), python version used by foobar interpreter doesn't support classes.